# How can use [public] folder in Rails Engine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I have a blog engine and add to a Rails App:

1. Add  `public` folder and file js to engine:

   \public\sliderengine\amazingslider.js
2. edit file `engine.rb` of Engine:

> ```
> class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
>     isolate_namespace Blorgh
>     initializer "static assets" do |app|
>     app.middleware.insert_before(::ActionDispatch::Static, ::ActionDispatch::Static, "#{root}/public")
>     end
>   end
> ```

3. Edit file `.gemspec` of engine:

> s.files = Dir["{app,config,db,lib,public}/**/*", "MIT-LICENSE",
>   "Rakefile", "README.md"]

4. Using file js in a file `index.html.erb` of engine:

> ```
>    <script src="sliderengine/amazingslider.js"></script>
> ```

Result : occur error when run Rails App:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/blog/sliderengine/amazingslider.js 404 (Not Found)
```

How can use [public] folder in Rails Engine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to copy public folder of engine to public/blog folder of Rails App

Answer (score -1):

Hm. Here's how I do it:

Put the js in the assets folder of the engine (I put it under the engine name):

```
app/assets/javascripts/blorgh/amazingslider.js
```

Then in the engine add:

```
#blorg/app/assets/javascripts/blorgh.js
//= require_tree ./blorgh
```

Then in the app

```
#application.js
//= require blorgh
```

Comment: Can't use public folder in Engine? If Rails app , it is ok.

Comment: Honestly, I don't know. I seemed more 'conventional' to me to use the asset pipeline. And it works flawlessly. But, maybe you can use public folder.

Comment: i using a lib, if convert to pipeline, i have to convert very much code  html.

Comment: If you say so. When I do the above, it inserts the appropriate `<script src="..."></script>` in the header of my main app. I don't know why you would have to convert code, but OK.

Comment: i only insert to:  file index.html.erb of engine